# Series ends with arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us take series $a^2$. Where $a = 1, 2, 3, …$

The entire series of $a^2$ is look like: $A = 1, 4, 9, 16, …$

First step: The difference between every two terms of $A$ is: $B$ = $3, 5, 7, …$

Second step: The difference between $B$ is:  $2, 2,… $ and looks like arithmetic progression.

In this problem, we have taken $a^2$ and within second step we have seen common difference and concluded this series as arithmetic series.

If you take $a^3$, within $3rd$ step we can conclude common difference is $3! = 6$ and arithmetic series.

My question is: How to prove the series $a^n$ for $a = 1, 2, 3,…$ gives common difference n! at $n$ th step, and gives arithmetic series. Also, I want to know any such similar observations are made so far.

Regards,
ATM

Comment: @vikrm! d=0 is not allowed

Comment: @vikram! I mean, at second step you can see the common difference of B is 2. This is an A.P. series.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are doing at each step is just the forward difference operator (see [Finite Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) at Wikipedia). In any case, you can prove your observation by induction on the step number. At step $0$ the function is a $n$-th degree polynomial with leading coefficient $1$. Then prove by induction that at step $t \in [0..n]$ the function is a $(n-t)$-th degree polynomial with leading coefficient $\prod_{k=1}^t (n+1-k)$. This would imply that at step $n$ the function is a $0$-th degree polynomial (which is a constant function) with leading coefficient $n!$.

Comment: ! could you prove it by induction please...

Comment: ! you have done, what I have given in my question. Could you help me to prove or prove my statement using Induction. Awaiting your response.

Comment: @ATM: Try it yourself first! You can edit your question and say what you've tried now.